# How to fetch records from a table that matches with all values in the other table

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-division

How to write a query that fetches all the drivers who drive all the available buses?

TABLE BUS

```
--------
BUS_ID
--------
1
2
3
4
```

TABLE DRIVER

```
-----------------------
BUS_ID  |   DRIVER_NAME
-----------------------
1   |   John
2   |   John
1   |   Max
2   |   Max
3   |   Max
4   |   Max
2   |   Bill
3   |   Ron
4   |   Ron
1   |   Ron
2   |   Ron
```

In this example it should return

```
DRIVER_NAME
-----------
Max
Ron
```

Note: Do not hard code any values in the query.

I have written the following

```
SELECT DRIVER.DRIVER_NAME
FROM   DRIVER
WHERE  BUS_ID = ALL( SELECT BUS_ID FROM BUS);
```

Comment: Search for *Relational Division*. `= ALL` only returns TRUE if all BUS_ID share the same value...

Comment: @Jalal your question is: *the drivers who drive all the available buses*. So the table buses contains all the buses or all the available buses?

Comment: @forpas Let me clarify, all the available buses mean all the records in bus table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grouping` with `having` clause :

```
SELECT D.DRIVER_NAME
  FROM DRIVER D
 GROUP BY D.DRIVER_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BUS);

DRIVER_NAME
-----------
Ron
Max
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c8a86274a33a16e3ec4e96bd855b222)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, group by d.driver_name and put the condition in the having clause:

```
select 
  d.driver_name
from bus b inner join driver d
on d.bus_id = b.bus_id
group by d.driver_name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from bus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DRIVER_NAME FROM
(SELECT D.DRIVER_NAME, 
COUNT(DISTINCT BUS_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY D.DRIVER_NAME) INDVDL,
COUNT(DISTINCT BUS_ID) OVER () TOTAL
  FROM DRIVER D)
 WHERE INDVDL = TOTAL
```

-- update --

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DRIVER_NAME
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            D.DRIVER_NAME,
            COUNT(DISTINCT BUS_ID) OVER(
                PARTITION BY D.DRIVER_NAME
            ) INDVDL,
            B.TOTAL   AS TOTAL
        FROM
            DRIVER D JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(1) AS TOTAL
                FROM
                    BUS
            ) B ON (1=1)
    )
WHERE
    INDVDL = TOTAL;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This will not work, if the there is a bus id 5 and none of the drivers drive it., then my answer should be null., but your query will give me max and ron.

Comment: I thought you wanted only operated buses from Driver table. I have updated the answer now, Please check.